# JavaScript/JQuery to bring div to the front of another

Tags: jquery, css

I have been searching for some code to bring one div in front of another upon the click of a button.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<a href="#" class="button">Toggle</a>

<div class="red">
    Red Content
</div>

<div class="blue">
    Blue Content
</div>
```

and the CSS code:

```
.red {
position: relative;
top: 100px;
left: 0px;
width: 200px;
height: 100px;
background-color: red;
color: white;
text-align: center;
line-height: 100px;
}

.blue {
position: absolute;
top: 127px;
left: 8px;
width: 200px;
height: 100px;
background-color: blue;
color: white;
text-align: center;
line-height: 100px;
}
```

I cannot figure out how to click the toggle button to have the "red" div appear over the "blue" div. Then upon another click, have the "blue" div appear over the "red" div again.

Here is the jquery code:

```
$(".red").click(function(){
$(".red").toggle();
$(".blue").hide();
});
```

thanks for any and all help!

Comment: look up `z-index` that may be of some help!!

Comment: I will do that! can z-index be applied to buttons?

Comment: want to hide one element. looks like emmaunel (below) solved my  problem. thanks for the help!

Comment: all good. The answer however is yes z-index can be applied to buttons. I didn't want to go into too much but I'm glad he go the answer for you. All in all if you want to just change the position in which one element is over another (not make it completely disappear) you can use that. Good luck :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One `<div>` has to be invisible at the starting point and both to be `toggled` on click.

```js
$(".button").click(function() {
  $(".blue, .red").toggle();
});
```

```css
.red {
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  display:none;
}
.blue {
  position: absolute;
  top: 127px;
  left: 8px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="button">Toggle</a>

<div class="red">
  Red Content
</div>

<div class="blue">
  Blue Content
</div>
```